# I need example for facebook chat authentication for android apps

Tags: facebook, authentication

I need an example for for facebook chat authentication for android apps like that python in the documentation

using xmpp/smack API

Comment: @Amer did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SMACK for android, check [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) to use with android.

I haven't experience with asmack, but I assume it should need the same hack as SMACK to autheticate with Facebook, please check this [blog post](http://yauritux.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/facebook-chat-with-smack-xmpp-api/).